What to do if crockery made impure by a dog is not washed according to the Sunnah in a non-muslim café?
My wife and I go to a café run by non-muslims (there are limited choices where we live unfortunately).
They have a separate bowl for dogs, so that it stays separate.
But my wife observed another customer letting their dog drink water from a glass intend for humans to use.
The glass got collected and washed in the dishwasher, but was not cleaned once with soil first.
Now we are paranoid about other customers letting their dogs make the crockery at the café impure, with no way for us to purify them.
We could stop going to this café, and seek out a Muslim run establishment, but even then you couldn't guarantee that something made impure by a customer's dog would be spotted and washed with soil (and expected everything to be washed with soil on the off chance it was made impure seem impractical and unreasonable to demand.)
What does one do when you can't reasonably follow the Sunnah on purifying crockery made impure by dogs?

I recently asked the same question to a teacher who spent almost a decade learning islam at a formal muslim academy
I asked him what do I do if I don't find soil.... He said intervening wash between 6 washes with water can be any medium, like a dish wash liquid, dish wash powder or even mineral talc in the form of dusting powder

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
